# checkbox data not insert in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, checkbox, sql-insert

I try to insert my checkbox data in CodeIgniter. but data did not inserted in the database.
here is my view file:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="WIFI" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="TV">
```

I am trying to use implode to convert the array into the string, but then I don't how to add in $data array, so they inserted in together

here is my controller:

```
     public function save()
     {
       $this->load->model('Partner_model');
       $feature = $this->input->post('feature');
      $fea=array(
             'feature'=>json_encode(implode(",",$feature)) 
                   );

      $user_data= array(
     'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
     'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
     'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
     'about' => $this->input->post('about'),
     'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
      'code' => $this->input->post('code')
     );
    if($this->Partner_model->save($user_data,$fea))
   {
       $msg = "save sucesss" ;
   }
   else
   {
       $msg = "not save";
   }

   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
   $this->load->view('partner_profile');
 }
```

& here is my model:

```
 public function save($data,$fea)
  {
     return $this->db->insert('property', $data,$fea);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function save()
 {
   $this->load->model('Partner_model');
   $feature = $this->input->post('feature');

   $user_data= array(
     'pname' => $this->input->post('pname'),
     'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
     'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
     'about' => $this->input->post('about'),
     'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
     'code' => $this->input->post('code'),
     'feature'=>json_encode(implode(",",$feature))
  );
  if($this->Partner_model->save($user_data)){
     $msg = "save sucesss" ;
  }else{
     $msg = "not save";
  }
  $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
  $this->load->view('partner_profile');
}
```

model file should be :

```
public function save($data) {
  return $this->db->insert('property', $data);
}
```

Comment: which datatype are you using for 'feature' column in 'property' table? Can you send the error message if any?

Comment: varchar data type

Comment: Try to print the $user_data variable before sending it to model. It should work fine If it prints the value for 'feature'. Also try to send without 'feature' column in $user_data array. There is no fault in the above code. Kindly tell us the error message you got from model using the below code.

  print_r($this->db->_error_message());

Comment: Then print your $feature variable and check whether the $feature variable is single dimensional or multidimensional array

Comment: hey i try to print $feature using print_r in controller, but its shows nothing, maybe i doing something wrong for to print statement, can you help me how to print $feature

Comment: i also paste your error code into model but when i try to run its shows page not working HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: use **print_r($this->input->post())** in the beginning of your controller's save method and check whether the post array has feature key and it's value. post the result here

Comment: if i enable your changes its shows page isn't working but with commented your changes "Array ( [pname] => [about] => [address] => [city] => [code] => [state] => Open this select menu )" its shows all other column

Comment: It shows all other column// **feature** column also showing ah? If not, check your HTML file whether the 'feature' input is defined inside **<form>** or not

Comment: ues feature column is in form, & if i try to put 'feature'=>json_encode(implode(",",$feature)) in $data array its shows that page is not working

Comment: Remove **json_encode** and try. I think @DFriend edited version is fine. Can you try that?

Comment: yes but its kinda complex for me, as i am new into codeigniter

Comment: if i remove json_encode & select wifi its shows Array ( [pname] => [abou] => [address] => [city] => [code] => [state] => Open this select menu [feature] => Array ( [0] => WIFI ) )

Answer (score 2):

Your model is faulty.

You are passing three arguments to `insert()` but the third you use is not appropriate.
That argument should be a boolean that indicates whether to escape values and identifiers or not.  You need to incorporate `$fea` into `$data` which should probably be done in the controller.

There is an easier way to create the array `$user_data` since it is essentially a copy of `$_POST` just use `$this->input->post()`.

Also, there is no obvious reason why you use `json_encode`. Unless you need it that way when you retrieve it from the DB there is no reason to bother with it. Consider removing `json_encode`.

First, change the model

```
public function save($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('property', $data);
}
```

Here's a revised save method

```
public function save()
{
    $this->load->model('Partner_model');
    $user_data = $this->input->post(); //makes a copy of $_POST
    $feature = $this->input->post('feature');
    if($feature) //because $feature will be null if no boxes are checked
    {
        $user_data['feature'] = json_encode(implode(",", $feature));
    }

    $msg = $this->Partner_model->save($user_data) ? "save sucesss" : "not save";

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
    $this->load->view('partner_profile');
}
```

**An explanation as requested via comments.**

A call to `$this->input->post('pname')` returns the value of `$_POST['pname']` if it is exists, but returns null if it does not exist.

When you create `$user_data` you make six calls to `$this->input()` with a different "key" each time to make a copy of `$_POST`.

`$this->input->post()` without any arguments returns the whole `$_POST` array. (See [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post))

```
$user_data = $this->input->post();
```

Makes a copy of `$_POST` using one line of code. It will include `$_POST['feature']` if any boxes are checked, but `$_POST['feature']` will not be set if no boxes are checked.

There are two ways to test if any boxes were checked. First we can test if `isset($_POST['feature']) == true` or we can test if `$this->input->post('feature') == true`. I use the second with the call

```
 if($feature)
```

Which is pretty much the same as any of the following lines

```
   if($feature != false)...
   if($feature != null)...
   if( ! empty($feature))...
   if( ! is_null($feature))...
```

In other words, `if($feature)` evaluates as true if `$feature` is set and is *anything* except `null`, `false`, 0, "0", "" (an empty string), array() (an empty array)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say about makes copy of $_POST,I change my model & also a controller but maybe i do it wrong:

Comment: controller:    $user_data= $this->input->post();
          $feature = $this->input->post('feature');
             if($feature) //because $feature will be null if no boxes are checked
             {
                 $user_data['feature'] = implode(",", $feature);
             }

      $user_data= array( //other data post);

Comment: I've added more details. Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: BTW, @SimbuDev and I give the same answer except I use fewer lines of code to get the same outcome. Plus mine takes into account the case where no boxes are checked.